# I can't pass data in segue - Swift3

Tags: swift3

I am studying IOS development reading a book titled IOS9 App Development Essentials.

When I try 'prepare segue part' there is an error. I think the code is changed from swift3, I don't know how figure it out.

code is following

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination =  segue.destinationViewController as!
    Scene2ViewControllerdestination.labelText = "arrived from scene1"
}
```

Comment: Please add what the error looks like!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work, you should use instance of `Scene2ViewControllerdestination`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destination =  segue.destinationViewController as! Scene2ViewControllerdestination
    destination.labelText = "arrived from scene1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) check the segue identifier (best practice)
2) create the object of destination view controller
3) using the object pass the required data

refer below code for your reference

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {

        if segue.identifier == YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER
        {
            let objSummery : SummeryVC = segue.destination as! SummeryVC
            objSummery.strUserID = YOUR_VALUE
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you are using the correct segue identifier. Segue identifier can be found in your `Main.storyboard` file.
   [image]
2. Check if your viewController is embedded in a UINavigationViewController.

If it is, then use something like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
 if segue.identifier == "your_identifier" {
      let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationViewController
      let sourceVC = destinationVC.viewControllers[0] as! Scene2ViewControllerdestination
      sourceVC.labelText = "arrived from scene1"
     }
}
```

If not, then use something like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
if segue.identifier == "your_identifier" {
let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! Scene2ViewControllerdestination
destinationVC.labelText = "arrived from scene1"
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code snippet.

- It’s syntactically incorrect (and after having written this answer I noticed that there's just a newline missing, between `Scene2ViewController` and `destination`, duh).
- `destinationViewController` was renamed to `destination`.
- Like Milap Kandalia suggests, check for the correct `identifier` (this will become important when you have multiple outgoing segues). Note that you have to set an identifier for your segue as bhakti123 illustrates.

Putting it all together, this should work:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MeaningfulIdentifier",
        let destination = segue.destination as? Scene2ViewController
    {
        destination.labelText = "arrived from scene1"
    }
}
```